# On adding a new record in Backbone it is adding only to the database, not the collection

Tags: javascript, php, database, codeigniter, backbone.js

This code works, but the only problem with this is, on creating new record using `this.collection.create({new post},{wait: true})` the values are getting updated in the database. But it is not adding it into the collection.

I put my full client side code below here. Also I am using the Codegniter Framework for database integration.

```
  (function(){

Backbone.emulateHTTP = true;
//Backbone.emulateJSON = true;

window.App = {
    Models:{},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {},
    Router: {}
};

window.vent = _.extend({},Backbone.Events); 

window.template = function(id){
    return _.template( $('#'+id).html()  );
};
```

//Model

```
   App.Models.Contact = Backbone.Model.extend({
validate: function(attrs){
    if( !attrs.first_name || !attrs.last_name || !attrs.email_address){
        alert('Fill the missing fields');
    }
}
});
```

//Collection

```
App.Collections.Contacts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: App.Models.Contact,
url: 'index.php/ContactsController/contacts'
});
```

// Views

```
   App.Views.App = Backbone.View.extend({
initialize: function(){
    vent.on('contact:edit',this.editContact,this);
    //console.log(this.collection.toJSON());        
    App.addContactView = new App.Views.AddContact({collection: App.Contacts});
    App.allContactsView = new App.Views.Contacts({collection: App.Contacts});
    $('#allcontacts').append(App.allContactsView.el);
},
editContact: function(contact){
    var editContact = new App.Views.EditContactView({model: contact});
    console.log(editContact.el);
    $('#editContactdiv').html(editContact.el);
}
});

    App.Views.AddContact = Backbone.View.extend({
el: '#addcontact',

initialize: function(){
    this.first_name = $('#first_name'),
    this.last_name = $('#last_name'),
    this.email_address = $('#email_address'),
    this.description = $('#description')
},

events: {
    'submit' : 'addContact'
},

addContact: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.collection.create({
        first_name: this.first_name.val(), // <=====    same as $this.el.find('#first_name')
        last_name: this.last_name.val(),
        email_address: this.email_address.val(),
        description: this.description.val()
    },{wait: true});    

    this.clearForm();
},

clearForm: function(){
    this.first_name.val('');
    this.last_name.val('');
    this.email_address.val('');
    this.description.val('');
}
});
```

//Edit Contact View

```
   App.Views.EditContactView = Backbone.View.extend({
template: template('editContactTemplate'),
initialize: function(){
    this.render();
    this.form = this.$('form');
    this.first_name = this.form.find('#edit_first_name');
    this.last_name = this.form.find('#edit_last_name');
    this.email_address = this.form.find('#edit_email_address');
    this.description = this.form.find('#edit_description');
},
events:{
    'submit form': 'submit',
    'click button.cancel': 'cancel'
},
render: function(){
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
},
submit: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.model.save({
        first_name: this.first_name.val(),
        last_name: this.last_name.val(),
        email_address: this.email_address.val(),
        description: this.description.val()
    });

    this.remove();
},
cancel: function(){
    this.remove();
}
 });
```

// All Contacts Views

```
    App.Views.Contacts = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName: 'tbody',   
initialize: function(){
    this.collection.on('add',this.addOne,this);
    this.render();
},
render: function(){
    this.collection.each(this.addOne,this);
    //console.log(this.el);

    return this;
},

addOne: function(contact){
    var ContactView = new App.Views.Contact({model: contact})
    //console.log(ContactView.render().el);
    this.$el.append(ContactView.render().el);
}

});
```

// A view for a single Contact

```
    App.Views.Contact = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName: 'tr',

template: template('allContactsTemplate'),
initialize: function(){
    this.model.on('destroy',this.unrender,this);
    this.model.on('change',this.render,this);
},
events: {
    'click a.delete': 'deleteContact',
    'click a.edit': 'editContact'
},
editContact: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    vent.trigger('contact:edit',this.model);
},
deleteContact: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.model.destroy();
},
render: function(){
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
},
unrender: function(){
    this.remove();
}
});

})();
```

Comment: Yes, I am adding to the same collection instance

Comment: Readers: the OP asked a [similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980729/after-adding-a-record-it-is-not-displaying-the-data-immediately-to-the-view) after this one, so you may wish to see if/how that one has been answered before expending substantial effort here.